# Jenkins: always checkout and build newest branch from remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins, build

we have a remote git repository wherein from time to time a new branch gets created (numbered).

I want my Jenkins to periodically check whether there is a new branch available and if yes to checkout and build this branch automatically.

Can you give me a hint how to approach this goal since i am quite a newbie in Jenkins administration.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following two plugins:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin

Both of them allows you to define a job which "duplicates" for each branch. The first uses pipelines which is the new "hip" way of defining jobs and the second uses regular free style job definition.